# Can a format string be specified to call .lower()?

Tags: python, string-formatting

When I specify a format string I'd like to make it call `.lower()` probably as part of the [`conversion`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-conversion) step:

```
# before:
"Bring out the holy {name!s}".format(name="RaBbIt")
# 'Bring out the holy RaBbIt'

# after:
"Bring out the holy {name!s.lower()}".format(name="RaBbIt")
# 'Bring out the holy rabbit'
```

I'll pass this format string to another class and I cannot alter how it uses it that's why I have no way to call `.lower()` inside the `.format()` call.

Can somehow the conversion to lowercase be specified in the format string?

Comment: `"Bring out the holy {name}".format(name="RaBbIt".lower())`

Comment: @poke `I'll pass this format string to another class and I cannot alter how it uses it that's why I have no way to call .lower() inside the .format() call.`

Answer (score 5):

No, `str.format()` and `format()` can not transform case (or otherwise call methods on the object). You'll have to do this before interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a black box which you only pass a format string to, you could pass your own object which has a `format` method, like this:

```
## this is a black box:
def doThings (formatString):
    print(formatString.format(name='RaBbIt'))
##

class LowerCaseFormatString:
    def __init__ (self, formatString):
        self.formatString = formatString

    def format (self, *args, **kwargs):
        args = [x.lower() for x in args]
        kwargs = { k: v.lower() for k, v in kwargs.items() }
        return self.formatString.format(*args, **kwargs)

fs = LowerCaseFormatString('Bring out the holy {name!s}')
doThings(fs)
# prints: 'Bring out the holy rabbit'
```

Comment: Seems like it might be a better idea to derive it from the built-in `str` class. i.e. `class LowerCaseFormatString(str):`.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.6+ you can use fstrings to accomplish this. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

```
>>> txt = 'aBcD'
>>> f'{txt.lower()}'
'abcd'
```